# How can I create two other matrices from a single mx3 matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have an `mx3` matrix `A` containing both integer and non-integers.

```
A = [1.5 1   1
     1   1.5 1
     2   1.5 1
     1.5 2   1
     1   1   1.5
     2   1   1.5
     1   2   1.5
     2   2   1.5
     1.5 1   2
     1   1.5 2
     2   1.5 2
     1.5 2   2];
```

What I would want is to create 2 new sets of matrices `A1` and `A2` such that I scan through each row of `A` and;

A1 = subtract 0.5 from any non-integer found in any column, and leave the integers as they are.

A2 = add 0.5 from any non-integer found in any column, and leave the integers as they are.

I would expect my final arrays to be:

```
A1 = [1 1 1
      1 1 1
      2 1 1
      1 2 1
      1 1 1
      2 1 1
      1 2 1
      2 2 1
      1 1 2
      1 1 2
      2 1 2
      1 2 2];

A2 = [2 1 1
      1 2 1
      2 2 1
      2 2 1
      1 1 2
      2 1 2
      1 2 2
      2 2 2
      2 1 2
      1 2 2
      2 2 2
      2 2 2];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your "non-integer" numbers are only x.5 you can simply use `floor` and `ceil`:

```
A1 = floor(A);
A2 = ceil(A);
```

if it's not the case use logical indexing:

```
A1 = A;
A1(round(A1) ~= A1) = A1(round(A1) ~= A1) - 0.5;
A2 = A;
A2(round(A2) ~= A2) = A2(round(A2) ~= A2) + 0.5;
```

Comment: Also, for the general case, `A1 = A-((mod(A,1)>0)*.5);` and similarly for `A2`

Comment: Thanks @Luis mendo. I got this well covered now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a condition, and depending on how you satisfy that condition either add or subtract 0.5:

```
cond = (rem(A3,1) ~= 0);%Generates a logical matrix
A1 = A; A2 = A;

%subtract and add 0.5 only to the elements which satisfy the condition:
A1(cond) = A1(cond) -0.5;
A2(cond) = A2(cond) +0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks @Murad Omar.